# Updates for Google Search, and Street View for Google Maps, listed but not able to be downloaded/installed

Tags: updates, lg-vs740

I have an LG ally that's just about a year old now, running 2.2.2. When I go to Market -> My Apps, there are two apps listed as "Not Installed" I'm having trouble with:

- [**Google Search**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox)
- [**Street View on Google Maps**](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.street#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmdvb2dsZS5hbmRyb2lkLnN0cmVldCJd)

[image]

(I have no interest in updating Facebook for Android, I luckily have an old, working version and I'm sticking with it.)

When I click on Google Search to download / install the update, the only button available  is "Open"; there is no "Install" button.

[image]

With Street View on Google Maps, there simply aren't any buttons at all!

[image]

If I didn't already install whatever these updates are, I'd like to install them. If I did already install them, I want them out of the "Not Installed" queue. How do I figure out which is the case? Is this a problem with my phone, or with the apps?

Comment: I've seen the same thing with different apps. Are you syncing to multiple accounts, per chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same problem with the new Market app a couple times now, the only solution I've found is to clear the Market data in `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> Market -> Clear data` (and `Clear cache` if it isn't already 0.00B). Now after you reopen Market, it should show the correct updates.

Comment: +1, this did help somewhat; Google Search and Street View are now listed as installed, but Google Maps has now become listed as uninstalled. It has the "Open" button, but no "Install" button. I've tried doing the same trick again, and it doesn't seem to take effect anymore. Maybe I should try uninstalling all the updates to Google Maps from the "Manage Applications" part of the settings, then (hopefully) be able to reinstall them?

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I do the same thing as onik suggested plus force close Market. When I start Market again, I have to accept the EULA again, but everything has returned to normal.

Comment: @Dennis: I followed your suggestion, but it didn't work for me. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Google Maps, and now it's listed correctly, which puts an end to my problem. onik and Dennis, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I just created an account on here so I could upvote this answer.  That's been getting on my nerves for weeks.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are the apps that comes with most of the phones. They must be installed in /system/app partition. You can't uninstall them without root. That's why no "uninstall" button.

The street view works with Google Maps, you can't open it directly. That's why no "open" button.

I don't have answer for why your system apps are not being able to update.